# adding (-1) to std::set iterator

Tags: c++

Why doesn't (1) work if (2) and (3) works?

```
std::set<int> st{1,2,3,4,5,6};
//(1)
std::cout<< *(st.end()-1);
//(2)
std::cout<<*--std.end();
//(3)
//for example
std::string str{"abcd"};
std::cout<<std::string(str.begin()+1, str.end()-1);
```

Comment: `std::set` iterators are [bi-directional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), so they support `--iterator` and `++iterator`, but they are not [random-access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), so they don't support `iterator-offset` and `iterator+offset`.  `std::string` iterators are random-access.

Comment: [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) may be of interest for (1).